# How do I track firebase-invites on firebase-analytics?

Tags: firebase-analytics, firebase-invites

When I setup firebase-invite and send succesful request to my friends how can I track the total and converted invitations. I see it on a firebase video but couldn't find any technical info for that. As far as I see on firebase-analytics it is not automated firebase-analytics process.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have alredy created the [dynamic links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android), Analytics tracking requires a tracking Id that you'll need to set using [`setGoogleAnalyticsTrackingId(String trackingId)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseinvites/interface_f_i_r_invites.html#a5f54fe6a0e25611d3db6c0363f88b6c1)
Just add your tracking ID to the builder and all the tracking events will be reported.
Make sure that you add dependency for Firebase Invites to your app-level `build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.0.2'
```

Comment: We did that and while we can see invite events in Google Analytics, nothing is shown in the (new) Firebase Analytics.

Comment: Current documentation says "If this method is not called, we will use the tracking Id set on the default Google Analytics tracker", meaning the id is set either you call it or not. Nothing to do with enable it.